# system.drawing usage in vba

Tags: vba, system.drawing

I want to use the system.drawing.dll in a VBA macro. I have added it as reference "Tools->References"
But now the trouble starts, I can not figure out how to use and call the methods in system.drawing.dll. I do get access to System_Drawing but there it ends.
I can declare in VBA

```
         Dim image1 as Bitmap
         Dim ImageFunc as System_drawing.Image
```

But then I fail to load (or set...?) an image to image1.

I have done the same thing in Visual Basic 2010, and it works fine. See blow for code

```
Imports System.Drawing
....
        Dim image1 As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromFile(Path, True), Bitmap)
        image1.MakeTransparent(Color.White)
        image1.Save(Path)
        image1.Dispose()
```

How do I apply the same code but in VBA? I have tried different Declare Functions, Set etc etc. but nothing works out. I kind off miss the basics even though I have googled and read about how to use C dlls in VBA.

Comment: There are no visible methods for this library that VBA recognizes as you can't (not supposed to use that library) within VBA. I think `Bitmap` is a .Net class. Yeah, it's com visible for the VB6 purpose probably but in VBA you can't use it. If you hit F2 it takes you to the object browser and you can preview that library members. There are no functions available for you to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I solved it by write a console app in vb.net. Then I just go for Call Shell in VBA and give the target file. Works fine but does not feel like a real professional solution since this function is done with external exe that is called from VBA. But at the end of the day.... it works and the png files is getting transparent.

Comment: not sure what you tried to achieve by using the System.Drawing library but I am glad your problem is solved. Calling an external exe from VBA is more "professional" than you probably think :)